# Join query in doctrine symfony

Tags: join, symfony1, doctrine

I have two tables userdetails and blog question The schema is

```
UserDetails:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: user_details
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
    name:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false

BlogQuestion:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: blog_question
  columns:
    question_id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    blog_id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
    user_id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
    question_title:
      type: string(255)
```

I am using one join query for retrieving all the questions and user details from this two tables  My join query is

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('*')
    ->from('BlogQuestion u')
    ->leftJoin('u.UserDetails p');
    $q->execute();
```

But it is showing this error Unknown relation alias UserDetails

Pls anybody help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why have you not set up a relationship in your doctrine?

```
UserDetails:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: user_details
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true

BlogQuestion:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: blog_question
  columns:
    question_id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    blog_id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
    user_id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
    question_title:
      type: string(255)
  relations:
    UserDetails:
      local: user_id
```

there is nothing in your yml to tell doctrine what it should be linking on when you left join. I have just build this myself and it does work

Comment: Thanks but when iam running symfony doctrine:build --all --no-confirmation
It shoeing an error Invalid schema element named "Local" at path BlogQuestion->columns->UserDetails

Comment: Then also it showing the same error

Invalid schema element named "Local" at path BlogQuestion->columns->UserDetails

Comment: wait 20 minutes, I will check my code in the office, although i have removed the upper case "L" with a lower case "l" above. You may also need to set id in UserDetails as a primary key.

Comment: UserDetails:
connection: doctrine
  tableName: user_details
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
      autoincrement: true

Comment: Hello THOmas, I have just built my new version I have edited above, and it does work. (now to remove it before i deploy :))

Comment: Now the query is working fine but iam getting the fields from the BlogQuestion only

$this->questions = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('user_id')
    ->from('BlogQuestion u')
    ->leftJoin('u.UserDetails p')
 ->execute();

Comment: The generated query is 

SELECT b.question_id AS b__question_id, b.user_id AS b__user_id FROM blog_question b LEFT JOIN user_details u ON b.user_id = u.id