# Doctrine DQL RIGHT JOIN?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, dql

Is it possible to do a RIGHT OUTER JOIN in [Doctrine 2 DQL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)?

Comment: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DC-742

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468187/join-query-in-doctrine-symfony

Comment: @THOmas: your question is for Doctrine 1. What is your point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there is still no way to do that in DQL, and the reason might be that it [does not make much sense](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/5225#issuecomment-162371154) from an ORM perspective, according to one of the lead developers.

Nevertheless, the feature request, although very old, is still open; so it *might* be implemented in the future.

Comment: Absolutely. While the first part of your answer may be correct, the justification wasn't very clear or helpful.

Comment: It does make sense imo. I really want to call a specific repository and do right join instead of calling another repository with left join. It may not matter to much in terms of ORM but it does to business logic and its meaning.

Answer (score -1):

In MySQL 5.7: My desired result was returned when using either `join`, `right join` or `right outer join`.

When I sought to translate this to Doctrine DQL, I returned the desired result using `->join(...`.